# Como transformar tags do xml para colunas de tabelas no html?

Tags: php, html, xml, dom

é o seguinte, quero transformar as tags do xml para uma tabela no html, exemplo (beeeem mirabolante, mas atende minha necessidade):

XML:

```
<animal>
 <humano>
  <clientes>
   <cliente>
    <Nome_cli>Froslass</nome_cli>
    <Idade_cli>18</Idade_cli>
    <Ende_cli>Rua xyz</Ende_cli>
   </cliente>
   <cliente>
    <Nome_cli>Gengar</nome_cli>
    <Idade_cli>16</Idade_cli>
    <Ende_cli>Rua xyz</Ende_cli>
   </cliente>
  </clientes>
 </humano>
</animal>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <table>
   <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Nome do Cliente</th>
    <th>Idade</th>                       
    <th>Endereço</th>                        
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>                    
   <tr>                        
    <td>Froslass</td>                       
    <td>18</td>                       
    <td>Rua xyz</td>                        
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Gengar</td>                        
    <td>16</td>                        
   <td>Rua xyz</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Queria deixa-lo assim: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUB6A.jpg
Em suma, quero pegar direto do xml, pois, se alguem fizer a alteração na questão da ordem dos dados, seria atualizado direto, o unico trabalho que eu teria era renomear os padrões, tipo Nome_cli para Nome do cliente, etc.etc, AHHHH outra coisa, como eu faço para percorrer direto as informação, no caso do xml não precisar de ficar xml->animal->humano->clientes->cliente  e ir direto em xml->cliente e pegar todas as informações desses clientes?
O que eu penso é fazer sempre pegar essas informações do xml e com ajuda do php ou javascript+DOM contar quais tags tem dentro da tag cliente criar as colunas, e pegar o valor de cada uma dessas tags e preencher a tabela: Nome do Cliente
                                                                Froslass
                                                                Gengar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sobre a questão**

> como eu faço para percorrer direto as informação, no caso do xml não
>   precisar de ficar xml->animal->humano->clientes->cliente e ir direto
>   em xml->cliente e pegar todas as informações desses clientes?

Utilizando a classe [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) do php (5,7) você consegue , segue um exemplo.

```
$file = new DomDocument();
$file->load("../myXmlFile.xml");
$clientes = $file->getElementsByTagName("clientes");

foreach($clientes as $cliente){
    echo $cliente->getAttribute("Nome_Cli");
}
```